# Anonymous user can view unpublished content

Tags: 8

Is there any way anonymous users can access unpublished pages using view?

I have a REST api for a custom content type that has setting of unpublished content and I want anonymous users can access it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can enable module Workflows which is currently packed in core since 8.3 and check for permission for anonymous user

> View any unpublished content

in /admin/people/permissions

Note: Not to confuse about the permission when enable only Workflows. You need to enable module Content Moderation(Core module) to make Workflows work. Once go to /admin/config/workflow/workflows you will see the the default workflow. Here is the permission after enable Content Moderation.
[image: Content moderation permission]

Comment: I didnt see that in the list of permissions after enabling it. Even without the module enabled, it has *View own unpublished content* but doesnt seems to work when I allow anonymous on it.

Comment: Surely you cannot see it, because to let Workflows module work you need to enable another module --> Content Moderation (in core too) to define a workflow. Then it will appear in permission

Comment: Thanks! But I found another module I posted in the answer without any configuration and it solves my prroblem.

Answer (score 1):

Found this module and solves my problem [View Unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished).

> This module allows you to grant access for **specific** user roles to view
>   unpublished nodes of a **specific** type. Access control is quite granular
>   in this regard.